# Listview and Datagridview are always disabled

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datagridview

I have a Winforms application which loads data using a datatable. I'm trying to display it in the forum that the user sees.

The data is loaded correctly and displayed in the listview or datagridview. However, it is always disabled. It shows a vertical scroll bar but doesn't allow me to scroll or select any data.

The data is put into the listview/gridview when the form loads.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your form disabled?  No one can answer this question without seeing your code.

Comment: @LarsTech You were right. No idea how I could have missed that. The form was indeed disabled. Must have been put that way by accident. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LarsTech This also solved my issue.