# Can't select row or control the scroll bar with DataGridVew

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, scrollbar

Maybe this's a newbie question.But I've been searching high and low  with no luck as whatever I tried didn't work.

I have a `DataGridView` named `dgvDeviceList` which contains 5 columns:ID,Device Name,Mac Address,RSSI and Advertisement Type in the FormMain window. 
When I use a method to scan the Bluetooth device nearby,and once find one,the DataGridView will add a new created row.

But I can't select row or control(scroll up/ down) the scroll bar when scanning is in process or stopped.And it looks that the `dgvDeviceList` doesn't have scroll bar.On some forums,it's described as a `multiple threading problem`,but unfortunately the method they provided can't work it out. Here's the code:

```
    int rowIndex = 1;

    private void SetupScanResultHandler()
    {
        ScanCallBack.ScanResultHandler = (result) =>
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in result.ScanRecords)
                {
                  //the following InvokeRequired method is provided by internet
                    if (dgvDeviceList.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        dgvDeviceList.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                        {
                            SetupDeviceListDataGridView(item);

                        }));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SetupDeviceListDataGridView(item);

                    }

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void SetupDeviceListDataGridView(CyScanRecord item)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dgvDeviceList.Rows[dgvDeviceList.Rows.Add()];
        row.Cells[0].Value = rowIndex;
        row.Cells[1].Value = Utility.GetDeviceName(item.AdvertisementData.RawData.Length, item.AdvertisementData.RawData);
        row.Cells[2].Value = Utility.InsertFormat(item.PeerDeviceAddress.Address.ToString("X12"), 2, ":");
        row.Cells[3].Value = item.RSSI.ToString() + "dBm";
        row.Cells[4].Value = item.AdvertisementType.ToString();

    }
```

[image: Screen shoot]

> I will be really grateful if you could post some code or direct me to
>   the right method that I should look into. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add values to DataTable instead of the DGV.  Make sure you add new row : DataRow newRow = new dt1.Rows.Add();

```
     private void SetupDeviceListDataGridView(DataRow row)
     {
                row[0] = 5;
                row[1] = 25;
                row[2] = 25;
                row[3] = 10;
                row[4] = 35;

                dgvDeviceList.DataSource = null;
                dgvDeviceList.DataSource = dataTabl;

      }
```

Comment: The 5,25,25…is the `FillWeight` for the column width instead of the value for the column. And I have set the device info value to the `dataTable `row,and then make `dataTable` add this row.At last, I bond the datasoure of `dgvDeviceList` with `dataTable`.Is there any wrong with the  process above ?

Comment: I will update the question description.I won't use a  `DataTable` instead that I 'll use `DataGridViewRow` and set value to ` row.Cells[i].Value`.With the result, the weird phenomenon is still exist!

Answer (score 0):

Oops!!I set the `Enable`property to `false`in the property list.The code `dgvDeviceList.enable = true;`can solve the issue.There should be no mistakes.

[Listview and Datagridview are always disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43497519/listview-and-datagridview-are-always-disabled)